# Transfering real time data from SQL Server to ArcMap without using PI Integrator

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.2, sql-server

I am new to GIS. Right now I am working on my senior project in which I have to find the fault in transmission line and show its location on a map using ArcMap 10.2. I have some readings of voltage and current in Microsoft SQL Server 2016. I want to transfer these values in **REAL TIME** to ArcMap 10.2.

Is it possible to do it directly, or do I have to use [PI Integrator for Esri ArcGIS](https://resources.osisoft.com/solutions/advanced-integrations/esri-arcgis/)?

Comment: How are the fault in transmission line locations being defined (segment ID, x/y coordinate...etc)?

Answer (score 0):

I would expect that this can be done using [Query Layers](https://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00s50000000n000000):

> A query layer is a layer or stand-alone table that is defined by a SQL
>   query. Query layers allow both spatial and nonspatial information
>   stored in a DBMS to be easily integrated into GIS projects within
>   ArcMap. Since query layers are using SQL to directly query database
>   tables and views, spatial information used by a query layer is not
>   required to be in a geodatabase.
>
> When working in ArcMap, you create query layers by defining a SQL
>   query. The query is then run against the tables and views in a
>   database, and the result set is added to ArcMap as a layer or
>   stand-alone table (depending on the query).
>
> The query is executed every time the layer is displayed or used in
>   ArcMap. **This allows the latest information to be visible without
>   making a copy or snapshot of the data and is especially useful when
>   working with dynamic information that is frequently changing.** The
>   query layers functionality works with any of the DBMSs supported by
>   ArcGIS.
>
> Query layers allow ArcMap to integrate data from geodatabases as well
>   as from DBMSs. Therefore, query layers can quickly integrate spatial
>   and nonspatial information into GIS projects independently of where
>   and how that information is stored.

I bolded one sentence to indicate why I think your real time requirements can be met using this functionality.